# A robust version of Harper's theorem

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

Let $S$ be subset of $\{0,1\}^n$ with cardinality $k$.

Denote by $\Gamma_r(S)$ the union of all Hamming balls with centers in $S$ and radius $r$.

Harpers's theorem states that $\Gamma_d(S)$ is minimal if $S$ is a Hamming ball (see also [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/247159/union-of-hamming-balls)).

Denote this minimal number by $V(k, r)$. My question is about a robust version of this theorem. Assume that $\Gamma_r(S) \le \text{poly}(n) \cdot V(k, r)$.

> Can we say that then 99% points of $S$ belongs to a union of $2^{o(n)}$
> Hamming balls with  radius $r_{\min} + o(n)$?

Here $r_{\min}$ is the smallest number such that the volume of Hamming ball with radius $r_{\min}$ is greater than $k$.

UPD: I have found two related papers: [Vertex-isoperimetric stability in the hypercube](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.02572)
 and  [Stability for vertex isoperimetry in the cube](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.09618)

The authors there prove that if  poly(n) = 1 + o(1) then almost all of $S$ belongs to a single Hamming ball.

UPD2: The question is also interesting if we assume that $r(n)=\Omega(n)$ and $p(n)=\text{const}$.

Comment: The last inequality in the post should be completely different, shouldn’t it?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov, yes, thank you.